# c# Test Automation/Plan example

Tags: c#, testing

I am looking for some Basic Test Automation/Plan Example using c#.
Any links/pointers are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I did that and I found some large frameworks but I am looks for a basic one to help me understand and make my changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to add some specifics of what you are trying to accomplish to get better answers.  If you are just starting to architect a framework I would suggest looking at the [following](http://angryweasel.com/Articles/Beautiful_Testing_chapter8.pdf) from Alan Page on large scale test automation.  If you are just looking for specific technique stuff you might want to take a look at [.Net Test Automation Recipes](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590596633) by James D. McCaffrey.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for some basic stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is WiPFlash](http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/), a little automation framework I am working on. I have linked an automated scenario for the pet shop which I'm using as an example app just below the pictures. You can also browse the code; everything called `SomethingBehaviour` is a unit test, and the two scenarios are acceptance tests.

Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but it might give you some ideas.